# Summation of number series power over exponent

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can one calculate this: $S =\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3}{4^n}$ ? I guess there must be a recurrent expression for elements, which could be transformed into an equation for $S$ by making $n \rightarrow \infty$, but I failed to get it.

Comment: $S=Li_{-3}(1/4)$ and $Li_{-3}(z)=\frac{z(1+4z+z^2)}{(1-z)^4}$, it is e. g. in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Particular_values), with lots of references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $n^3=6\binom{n+1}{3}+\binom{n}{1}$ it is sufficient to recall that:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\binom{n}{1}x^n = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2},$$
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\binom{n+1}{3}x^n = \frac{x^2}{(1-x)^4}$$
to have:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^3}{4^n}=6\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{4^2}}{\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)^4}+\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}=\color{red}{\frac{44}{27}}.$$

Comment: Awesome! But could you give me a clue how to prove these two properties?

Comment: @user3475298: start from $\sum_{n\geq 0}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ and differentiate both sides multiple times.